# Вывести цикл для формы при отправке данных

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы отправлялись разные значения, пока что только первый элемент. Получаю ответ всегда только один результат, вместо разных.

```js
var formb = document.querySelectorAll(".addcartpost");
function addCart(e) {
    //e.preventDefault()
    var fd2 = new FormData()
    fd2.append("id_pr", document.getElementById('id_pr').value)
    fd2.append("quantity", document.getElementById('id_quantity').value)
    axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
    axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN"
    axios.post("http://127.0.0.1/catalog/basket/add/", fd2)
        .then(function(resp){
            //alert(resp.data)
            //formb.innerHTML = resp.data
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err)
        })
}
formb.forEach(Item => {
    Item.addEventListener("click", (e) => addCart(e.preventDefault(),Item.innerHTML));
})
```

Comment: У тебя обращение к элементам идет по ИД... А ИД должен быть уникальным на странице. Это все нужно поменять на класс и работать "относительно родителя", а не `document`.

Comment: я пробовал класс прописать почему то не помогло

Comment: fd2.append("id_pr", document.querySelectorAll('.id_pr').value)
fd2.append("quantity", document.getElementById('.id_quantity').value)

Comment: Просто написать класс вместо ИД не особо поможет делу... Тут нужно потом правильно с этим работать (см.мой ответ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментариях я писал про вот такой вариант работы с формой и полями...

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.test').forEach(o => o.addEventListener('submit', test))
//
function test(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const v = this.querySelector('.name').value
  alert('Отправляем ' + v)
}
```

```html
<form class='test'>
  <input class='name' value='Петя' />
  <button>Отправить</button>
</form>
<form class='test'>
  <input class='name' value='Вася' />
  <button>Отправить</button>
</form>
<form class='test'>
  <input class='name' value='Оля' />
  <button>Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: спасибо! Чуть не ушел вдебри на ровном месте)